# Cryptography with python

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography

I am new in this field, Would you help me ? Each byte in my cipher text (encrypt3) is interpret as an integer between 0 to 255.For each byte Plaintext=Ciphertext -100 (mod 256). In the following code I have error:      newbyte=c.to_bytes(1,byteorder=sys.byteorder,signed=False)
OverflowError: can't convert negative int to unsigned
Any help would be appreciated.

```
import sys
f=open("encrypt3.dat","rb")
s=f.read(100)
d=bytearray(s)
print (len(d))
strnew=''
newbyte=b''
for c in d :
    c=c-100 % 256
    newbyte=c.to_bytes(1,byteorder=sys.byteorder,signed=True)
    strnew=strnew + newbyte.decode('latin1')

print(strnew)
```

Comment: You are in effect using a byte-based Caesar Cipher.  To move on from a Caesar Cipher, have a look at [Vigenère](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigenère_cipher) or perhaps [RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4) for your next cipher exploration.  You did well to go for a byte-based implementation rather than an alphabet based implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modulus operator (`%`) is processed before the subtraction operator (`-`), so your statement `c=c-100 % 256` is equivalent to to `c=c-(100 % 256)`, or just `c=c-100` (because `100 % 256 == 100`). As a result, your code will crash whenever it encounters a character with an ASCII code less than 100 (='d').

You can fix this by changing `c=c-100 % 256` to `c=(c-100) % 256`.

Read up on [operator precedence in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).